# Routing URLs started with a special character

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, url-routing

In ZendFramework, i want to route urls started with `~` to special controller and action, so that other urls don't start with `~` work properly.

For example see below two url routings:

```
mysite.com/~user
```

and

```
mysite.com/admin
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try and use this within your Bootstrap

```
// Get the instance of the router
$router = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter();

// Set up a new regex router to match routes starting with ~
$route = new Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex(
    '(^\~)',
    //This route should use a 'special' controller
    array(
        'controller' => 'special',
        'action'     => 'index'
    )
);

// Add the new route to the router
$router->addRoute('archive', $route);
```

You will need a controller called `Special` to respond to the requests routed vis this router.

Comment: I try it, and error message is `Invalid controller specified (~user)`.

Answer (score -1):

NOt sure about zend specifically, but they best way to do it would be to add a hash lookup table before the url router does its business.

So lets say mod_rewrite converts this:
mysite.com/~user

to this:
mysite.com/index.php?path=~user

then you would do something like this:

```
$path = $_GET['path'];

$url_mod = array(
  '~user'=>'my_other_controller',
  'admin'=>'my_other_controller',
);

if(isset($url_mod[$path)) {
 $path = $url_mod[$path]; 
}
```

Comment: Notice to question, i need a routing `URL` or any approach that i can use in ZendFramework.